# APEX row selector

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm displaying my results on an interactive grid. I'd like to be able to select multiple rows and click an edit button that will open up an “edit” form.  I am having a number of problems:

1. Retrieve the car IDs of the rows selected. (I am having trouble accessing column values, I can access item values)
2. Pass a collection or array of ids to the edit form.
3. Save the collection.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Added more code in answer box by accident...……..

Comment: See the following blog post from Monica Godoy for a great example that will get you pretty far: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/extending-interaction-to-interactive-grids As for proxying the values from the modal page to the parent page, see the last two parts of this older blog post: http://www.danielmcghan.us/2016/03/tutorial-creating-component-similar-to.html Combining concepts from both of the posts should get you there, but let us know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress but I am a little stuck. I followed the oracle blog and it was vey helpful.  So on the attribute of the region I added the following code:

```
function (config) {
  var $ = apex.jQuery,
  toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
  toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3");

  toolbarGroup.controls.push(
  {
    type: "BUTTON",
    action: "updateCar",
    label: "Edit Selected Cars",
    hot: true,
  });

   config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
   config.initActions = function (actions)
   {
      // Defining the action for activate button
     actions.add(
     {
       name: "updateCar",
       label: "Edit Selected Cars",
       action: updateCar
     });
   }

  function updateCar(event, focusElement)
  {
    var i, records, model, record,
    view = apex.region("ig_car").widget().interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");

     var vid = "";
     model = view.model;
     records = view.getSelectedRecords();
     if (records.length > 0)
     {
       for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
       {
         record = records[i];
         //alert("Under Development " + record[1]);
         vid = vid + record[1] + "||";
         apex.item("P18_CAR").setValue(vid);// This is not needed just to test 
          //the output
     // call next page
         // pass array as sql source or directly on page 
       }
      }
    }
  return config;
 }
```

This works.  A button is displayed and when selected it gets the values from the interactive grid.  The part I am stuck is how to call the next page and pass the multiple values (2 columns) to the page to be displayed and in a query to do an update.

Thank you if you can help me accomplish this!